# Deployment issues of Django CMS Project on Ubuntu Server

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, django-cms

I'm a rookie to Django and Django CMS but definitely enjoying the framework thus far.

I have a question regarding deploying a Django CMS project on Ubuntu Server. When we deploy it on the Ubuntu desktop version, the project works just fine without any issues, but on the server, we run into trouble with the `CMS admin interface`. Although the content of the sidebar is functional, it does not collapse anymore and once we select an option from the CMS toolbar, the modal window that pops up is unresponsive.

Initially i thought there was an issue with my project, but then we just installed a basic django CMS project on the server itself, without any other apps, and the issue still persisted. I am using **Django 1.7.3**, **Django CMS 3.0.9**, and **Ubuntu Server 14.04**. I am unable to determine what the issue is and no errors are thrown. Tried searching the web for this issue, but we couldn't find any similar issues.

**UPDATE:**

So i was able to narrow down the problem here to some extent. Found out that the problem was with the browser. A few versions of chrome were giving me these issues. IE and Firefox were working just fine.

**UPDATE 2:**

As @mkoistinen suggested, this problem had been occuring on devices with touch-screens and mouse capabilities. Please look at [this issue](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/3688).

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Yes, would also check the console first - sounds like a javascript error.

Comment: Hi i checked for javascript errors. But there weren't any. I wanted to check if the click functions on the sidebars were triggering but it didnt help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run Django and CMS, etc. on Ubuntu servers all day long, so there is not an issue with the OS for sure.

Having said this, running Django locally can be very different than running it in a production environment. Locally, runserver takes care of a lot of things you have to address yourself on a server under the WSGI implementation of your choice.

It sounds like you have WSGI configured well enough to get Django to respond, but you may be having trouble with your STATIC and MEDIA paths. Definitely check the settings for these items.

Another thing to look at is, did you run `python manage.py collectstatic` on the server? If not, the static files from your packages will not have been copied into your STATIC_ROOT, which could easily lead to the condition you describe above.

If your client is both touch- and mouse-capable, please note that this is an issue that is fixed in 3.0.10.

Comment: Hi Martin, yes I did run the collectstatic command and made sure that my nginx is pointing to serve those files correctly...

Comment: But it is not just the static files. When i do a runserver command from the shell, it still does the same.

Comment: Hi @mkoistinen. So i was able to narrow down the problem here to some extent. Found out that the problem was with the browser. A few versions of chrome were giving me these issues. IE and Firefox were working just fine. Do you think CMS might have some issues with a few versions of chrome?

Comment: Could be, but I use it as my primary dev. browser and I haven't seen this. Are you sure there aren't any JS errors in the console?

Comment: Yeah... M very sure there are no errors.. Just realized this error was happening on new computers and not old ones. I have a new machine which I got like a year ago. But my friend whose machine is pretty old like 3yrs old works fine with chrome... I am very confused..

Comment: Is the new computer both mouse and touch-capable, but any chance? If so, have a look here: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/3688. And if this is indeed the issue you're experiencing, I would perhaps like to recruit some help from you to fix it, as I have no such device.

Comment: Yes. now that you mentioned about it, it is happening on all the devices with touch-capabilities. Tried it on my colleagues laptops too which had touch-capabilities and it happened again. I would definitely love to help you on this issue.

Comment: hi martin. For some reason, the problem started again. I tried the latest release 3.0.10.

Comment: Hi @crozzfire I've just checked, the changes are in the release. Perhaps you have old, cached JS files? Also, this is not the best place to be posting issues, please open an issue at https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues.